# Como Inicio sesión en wordpress mediante formulario y control de acceso en php

Tags: php, wordpress, sesiones, redireccionamiento

```php
<?php

// iniciamos la sesion
session_start();

// CONTROL DE ACCESO LOGIN 
include "..//conexion.php";

if ($con->connect_error) {
  die("Connection fallida: " . $con->connect_error);
}

// verificamos si ha sido pulsado el boton acceder en
// el formulario de login

if ( !empty($_POST["btningresar"]) ){
  if (
    !empty($_POST["usuario"]) and 
    !empty($_POST["password"])
  ){
    $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

// Incluir el archivo de WordPress para tener acceso a sus funciones

    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require_once('..//wp-load.php');

// Comprobar si el usuario ya está logueado

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
      echo "El usuario ya está logueado.";
    } else {

// Realizamos la consulta para obtener el hash de
// la contraseña almacenada en la base de datos

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM xcd_users where user_login = '$usuario'";
      $result = $con->query($sql);
      if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ){

// Obtiene el hash de la contraseña de la base de datos

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $hashed_password_from_db = $row['user_pass'];

// Verificamos si la contraseña ingresada si coincide con el hash de la B.D

        require_once('..//wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
        if (
          $wp_hasher->CheckPassword(
            $password, $hashed_password_from_db
          )
        ){
          echo "¡Contraseña correcta! Acceso permitido.";

// Almacenamos las credenciales verificadas en un array

          $creds = array(
            'user_login'    => $usuario,
            'user_password' => $password,
            'remember'      => true
          );

// Iniciar sesión en wordpress con las credenciales verificadas del usuario

          $user = wp_signon($creds);

// Verificar si hubo un error en el inicio de sesión

          if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
            echo "Error al iniciar sesión: ".$user>get_error_message();
          } else {
            echo "Inicio de sesión exitoso.";

// Obtenemos el rol del usuario logeado

            $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
            $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
// Obtener el primer rol asignado

// Redirigimos al usuario según su rol
            switch ($user_role){
              case 'administrator':
// Redirigimos al panel de administración
                wp_redirect(admin_url());
              exit;

// Otros roles por defecto en WordPress

              wp_redirect(home_url(
                'aqui la pagina de redirecionamiento'
              ));
              exit;
            }
          }
        } else {
          echo "¡Credenciales incorrectas"; exit ();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

He creado un formulario de inicio de sesión para WordPress, utilizando un archivo al cual he llamado login.php desde el que envío mediante POST las credenciales del usuario, estas son recogidas en otro archivo donde son comparadas con las existen en la B.D. Hasta aquí todo bien, pero no encuentro la manera correcta de abrir sesión redireccionando a una página web (WordPress) con su rol correspondiente.
El código expuesto a continuación despues de introducir las credenciales y enviar el formulario me devuelve el siguiente error: " ¡***Contraseña correcta! Acceso permitido. Error al iniciar sesión: Autenticación fallida***."

Comment: Wordpress tiene Login para usuarios del dominio, para usuarios normales (mi cuenta), tiene roles, tiene todo lo que tu estas haciendo. ¿Alguna razón especial para reinventar la rueda?

Comment: Si, ya sé que Wordpress tiene su propio login y existen plugins para su personalización. El problema lo tengo, porque si un usuario quiere iniciar sesión tiene que hacerlo utilizando por defecto  el archivo Wp-Login o Wp-Admin y por alguna razón que desconozco y créeme que he probado de todo, se hace eterno su aparición, e incluso si lo intentas por Android,  de modo que, si creo un formulario login sin llamar a estos archivos, mandar por POST las credenciales , verificarlas y finalmente abrir sesión según el rol en mi pagina, los tiempos se reducirán notablemente.

Comment: Pero estas buscando "una solución" errada para otro problema, es como que estas evitando resolver tu problema principal. Otra cosa, aunque los usuarios "normales" usen `wp-login` lo hacen por medio de otras llamadas o páginas como My Account o un modal.

Quizás te resulte mejor resolver porqué carga tu login tanto. Puedes poner la web para darle una revisada?? PD: Yo no te podré ayudar con lo de tu pregunta principal, lo digo por si no quieres "perder tu tiempo conmigo" 

Comment: `Nunca es perder el tiempo si sirve para aprender. Entiendo lo que dices perfectamente @OCHOA y es la misma pregunta que en su día me formulé .¿Para qué voy a hacer algo que ya lo lleva implícito WordPress?. Pero a veces la carga puede demorarse más de 30 s. solo para que salga el formulario login. Quizás no sea este el foro para solucionar este problema, he probado de todo, cambiar plugin o anularlos, actualizar y limpiar caché lo que me queda seria compactar la base de datos para que el redireccionamiento sea más rápido, no sé. ...

Comment: ... Te paso la web y observa que si accionas el botón de acceder como usuario, el login debería de aparecer entre 1 o 3 s. y sin embargo suele tardar 20-30 s o incluso más.  [https://www.sendatoledo.es ]. Gracias @OCHOA

Comment: Me da curiosidad este topic, en efecto acá no te van ayudar al ser WP de una empresa con su propio soporte. Voy abrir un chat y si gustas lo vemos ahí.

Comment: [Visita mi chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147678/ochoa-vault-713) y hablemos cuando puedas, te iré escribiendo algunas cosas ahí

Comment: He metido las narices en vuestro chat, dejando un extenso comentario fruto de mi experiencia de 10 años en Wordpress. Todo lo que puedas hacer a un nivel más bajo, dependiendo lo menos posible de WP y sus plugin, hazlo. No te arrepentirás. No tienes por qué permanecer atado a WP para lo que quieres hacer aquí.